# i have a query that finds document ID's from a "user-saved" collection then another to search a "posts" collection to find all posts with that doc id

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app where users can post content and then save the posts like on Instagram and I want to make it so they're able to see the posts they've saved. I've successfully made a function to get all the document IDs from the "user-saved" collection but I don't know how to pass these into another function that can query my "posts" collection to find the posts with matching IDs.

this is the code to find the ids from the "saved-posts" collection;

```
static func FindUserSavedPosts(uid: String) async throws {
    let snapshot = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("user-saves").getDocuments()
    for document in snapshot.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID)")
        try await FetchUserSavedPosts(documentid: document.documentID)
        }

    }
```

this is the code that finds the posts with the matching ids;

```
static func FetchUserSavedPosts(documentid: String) async throws -> [Post]{
    let postssnapshot = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").wherefield("id", isEqualTo: documentid).getDocuments()
    return try postssnapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Post.self)} )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you store the saved post's content under `user-saves`? That way you won't need the additional loads. --- This is known as denormalization, and is extremely common when dealing with NoSQL databases. If you're new to that, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I could do this but I feel the app would need more loads to keep the data such as comments and likes synced across all instances of it, I could make a sub-collection within the posts data to contain a list of user ids of people who have saved it then just query that to find the posts I've saved but I don't know how to return the post documents data as it would be a different document to the one I've saved. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense and ill try to clarify.